# Powershell, check for blank input, zero evaluates as blank/null

Tags: powershell, input, null

I am trying to validate a simple powershell input. I want to allow the number zero as valid input, but blank (just pressing enter) is not valid input. I am having the most difficult time with the validation. Everything works EXCEPT when the user enters the number zero.
I have tried checking the length, checking for null, etc. 
Consider the code below. 
If you enter 0 (zero) the output is the same as if you just press [enter] (no input)

```
Pick a number 0-6: 0
You picked 0
blank input
equals zero
too short


$OUchoice = -1
do
{
    try{
        $OUchoice = Read-Host "Pick a number 0-6" 
    }
    catch{
        write-host "invalid input"
    }

    Write-Host "You picked $OUchoice"

    if ($OUchoice -gt 6) {write-host "too high"}
    if ($OUchoice -lt 0) {write-host "too low"}
    if ($OUchoice -eq "") {write-host "blank input"}
    if ($OUchoice -eq 0 ) {write-host "equals zero"}
    if ($OUchoice -eq $null ) {write-host "Null"}
    if (!($OUchoice)) {write-host "too short"}  
}
until (($OUchoice -ge 0) `
        -and ($OUchoice -le 6) `
        -and (($ouchoice)))

write-host "OK"
```

I have tried -eq $NULL and -eq "". What is the proper way to allow zero and disallow blank input?

Comment: What about this isn't working exactly?

Comment: I could not reproduce your results with the given code.

Comment: with the given code, simply pressing [enter] (null input) processes the same as entering zero. I want to allow zero as valid input and not allow null input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. I ensure that the $OUChoice is an Int when you compare it against other numbers. This ensures that null input is a 0 and also allows for negative values.

```
$OUchoice = -1
do
{
    try{
        $OUchoice = Read-Host "Pick a number 0-6" 
    }
    catch{
        write-host "invalid input"
    }

    Write-Host "You picked $OUchoice"
    Switch ($OUchoice) {
         {
            [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($OUchoice)} {
                write-host "Null Input"
                Break
        }
         {
            [int]$OUchoice -gt 6} {
                write-host "too high"
                Break
        }
         {
            [int]$OUchoice -lt 0} {
                write-host "too low"
                Break
        }
         {
            [int]$OUchoice -eq 0 } {
                write-host "equals zero"
                Break
        }         
    } 
}

    until (([int]$OUchoice -ge 0) -and ([int]$OUchoice -le 6) -AND (-NOT [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($OUchoice)))
write-host "OK"
```

Comment: This still allows you to enter no input. I need to allow zero as an input and not allow blank input

Comment: I updated my code to see if it better meets your requirements.

Comment: When you run this code what happens when you press [enter] at the prompt without entering any input? Please share your results. @boeprox

Comment: I get `You Picked` followed by `Null Input` and then it re-prompts for input.

Comment: strange, that is not what I am receiving. I get: 
`You picked 0`  
`equals zero`  
`OK`

Comment: Did you try the latest code that I posted. You also might want to reopen your PowerShell session as '$OUChoice' might still be cast as an Int. Or do 'Remove-Variable OUChoice'

Comment: upgraded my powershell ver from 3.0 to 4.0 (on Win2008R2). It is working as expected. Marking as answered. Thanks much for your help

Answer (score 5):

Problem lies in this:

```
PS> 0 -eq ""
True
```

When two values of different type are compared second argument is casted to the type of the first. Unfortunately for you:

```
PS> [int]""
0
```

empty string when casted to `int` produces `0`. In your case fix is easy: just reverse the order of operands as `0` casted to string would end up being `'0'`:

```
if ("" -eq $OUchoice) {write-host "blank input"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest your ifs (I didn't test much, but did check the zero and blank cases):

```
if (-not ($OUchoice -eq ""))
{
        if ($OUchoice -gt 6) {write-host "too high"}
        if ($OUchoice -lt 0) {write-host "too low"}
        if ($OUchoice -eq 0 ) {write-host "equals zero"}
        if ($OUchoice -eq $null ) {write-host "Null"}
        if (!($OUchoice)) {write-host "too short"}
}
else
{
    Write-Output "blank input"
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\users\mattp_000> .\x.ps1
Pick a number 0-6:
You picked
blank input
Pick a number 0-6: 0
You picked 0
equals zero
OK
PS C:\users\mattp_000> .\x.ps1
Pick a number 0-6: 3
You picked 3
OK
PS C:\users\mattp_000>
```

Comment: The output is the same, 0 and [no input/blank input/just press enter] yield the same results.

Comment: No, it does different things: `PS C:\users\mattp_000> .\x.ps1
Pick a number 0-6:
You picked
blank input
Pick a number 0-6: 0
You picked 0
equals zero
OK`